# Horizontal scrollbar .NET CF

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, scroll, widget

I'm looking for a widget that supports horizontal scrolling.
The widget must hold multiple rows of text.

The `ListBox` and `ListView` are ideal for this task, except that they don't support horizontal scrolling.

The `TreeView` widget supports horizontal scrolling, but it's really slow with adding new rows (nodes). So I'm not a huge fan of it.

I'm using Visual C# with the .NET 3.5 Compact Framework.

Am I missing a property of the used widgets, or is there another suitable widget available?

Comment: If the number and width of the columns in a ListView exceed the width of the control, there is a horizontal scrolling, no?

Comment: No, it will cut off the text in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay for a control the [Resco Smart Grid](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/details.aspx?comp=SmartGrid&p=WindowsMobile) has the option to have horisontal scroll bars when the columns exceed the width of the control. So you should be able to add one column and use it like a list view.

Comment: The widgets look really slick, but the price is way too expensive.

Comment: Yeah, We were fortunate that we managed to convince management that it was worth it. As a result our UIs look much better, and behave better, than the rest of the applications on the device.